# Compiling from Linux driver for a PCI (not PCI-E) video capture card to use in OSX

Tags: macos, video, driver, video-capture

Is there a way to convert and compile a kernel driver from linux to use it on OSX? I still use a very old Philips SAA7134 chipset based analog video capture card in my machine. This computer though is a hackintosh, so I have the benefit of having a PCI slot. Currently, I am still booting to Windows to use the card, but just out of curiosity i'd wanted to ask if it would be possible. I found source code for linux drivers for this chipset here: https://gitlab.cs.fau.de/me61sewa/passt-mac/tree/fdd70c3399fc448a87487b287f4f0dcfb2e9c52c/drivers/media/video/saa7134

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is off-topic on so many levels that I've been kind & voted to close it as a 'software development' request. Hackintosh is also off-topic… also, no Intel Mac has ever had [plain] PCI

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to just recompile a kernel driver for Linux for macOS.

It is possible to convert them - but doing so requires developer competencies in both Linux and macOS kernel areas. I.e. this is definitely not something a normal user can do. It cannot be automated.

What you might be able to do instead is to run a virtualized Linux, and use PCI passthrough to give the Linux kernel access to the raw hardware interface.